# JavaFX change the blue color of the TableView selection row bar

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

Everything I found searching for an hour does not work in my `TableView` with javaFX8, **the selection row bar** still is always blue.

*Tried all of this*:

[Javafx ListView selection bar text color when using CellFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062754/javafx-listview-selection-bar-text-color-when-using-cellfactory)

How do i change the color of the blue `TableView` selection row bar?

`tableView.setStyle("...");?`

As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS5Ch.jpg) I have different text styles set in the cellFactory of some columns and it's hard to read with this dark-blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the `.table-row-cell` CSS style class:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #005797;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 1;
}
```

Put this code into a CSS file and then add the file to the list of CSS stylesheets of the `TableView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to do it without the css file with setStyle all the time, but seems i just use it like this cause it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
.table-row-cell:selected {

    -fx-background-color: #EFEFEF;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;

}
```

To change the text color i had to add the following:

```
.table-row-cell:selected .text {

    -fx-fill: black ;

}
```